# When to use User Controls in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, user-controls

I have a view that Filters a DataGrid and I want to use the the exact same filtering with the same collection (apart from the columns will be different) in a different view.

Of course I dont want to duplicate the XAML in this new view, so is this when a user control would be the correct thing to do?

My only problem is that a new DataGrid will be put underneath in the new view so would this be possible? And as I said above, the columns also may be different in the filtering, so again, possible within a user control?

Thanks

Comment: You can use the underlying list collection view on the items source.  IF, caveat, if the underlying collection inherits from IList

Comment: I have the collection in memory, so that's fine, but I dont want to duplicate the XAML in one view to another.

Comment: Now I understand better.  You can use a custom control or the same control with template selectors.

Comment: Would a ControlTemplate stored under application.resources work? (what I done from research now)

Comment: Yes, that's fine.  You can place it in the app resources or in a resources only assembly.  Either way is fine.

Answer (score 0):

A UserControl should be used when wanting to create a new kind of control for your UI, or derive an existing control and enhance its capabilities.

What you need sounds like a Style, where you want to set certian properties of your control to certian values:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
  <Setter Property="Template">
     <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
             <Grid>
                 <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background"/>
                 <ContentPresenter/>
             </Grid>
         </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks, so basically I should create a user control, and use styles if I want certain functionality changed?

Comment: Its just the fact I will need to use the same XAML and the filter C# code on my new view, surely I dont need to duplicate both of them in the new view