# Control Template creating one instance in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, controltemplate

I've looked at using a control template to use the same XAML code between two views. However, where do I store this Control template so both views can access it and therefore display the controls I need?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both **views are under same window**, you can store **`ControlTemplate`** under **`Window.Resources`** and if both **view belongs to different windows** store that under **`Application.Resources`**.

Comment: Thank you Rohit, do I just create the Application.Resources in the main window or under any view?

Comment: No `Application.Resources` are declared inside `App.xaml`.

Comment: Thanks, will accept when SO lets me, is this the best way of duplicating a control i.e. a datagrid that filters between views, that is my problem.

Comment: Why not to create `UserControl` and use that across both views?

Comment: Thats what I wanted in the first place but was told not too! 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23181886/when-to-use-user-controls-in-wpf?noredirect=1#comment35455635_23181886

Comment: Its just there may be a small differences in both (mainly a column or two different in the datagrid) if this is OK in a user control, I will use one

Comment: `UserControl` is fine. You can expose custom dependency property (in case want to bind column names from outside otherwise create normal CLR property and set that from outside) to get columns on which you want filtering and write according to value of DP set.